# Context condition per menu (not menu item)

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation

I'm using Context module on Drupal 7 to show menu block on pages that's listed in that menu only.

Everything's good, I set 'Menu' condition and reaction is to show the block in some region, but the problem is that I must select menu items in condition and since items changes all the time I need to update Context all the time.

Is there some solution to select menu and not menu item, or to select menu item and automatically to include all submenu items?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to select a menu itself in Context Conditions.

Maybe you have something else common among those menu items that you can combine in different Conditions to get the same result? Maybe paths are similar? Or Content types?

Alternatively you can use a module other than Context just for this particular need: [Blocks per menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/blocks_per_menu).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `menu` as condition select `path` and enter the relative paths, like:

> articles
>
> articles/*
>
> page1
>
> page2
>
> content/*
>
> **content-type-url**/*

Do you have specific reason to use menu as condition? just wondering!